# Django Auth User and Custom User

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-models, django-forms

So far, I have been creating a user class in Django without inheriting **AbstractBaseUser** or **AbstractUser** classes. For example,

```
class User(models.Model):
    realname          = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    username          = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    birthday          = models.DateField()
    phone             = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    password          = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    ...
```

Now I am thinking about creating a user model that actually inherits AbstractBaseUser class.

**My question is, in what ways does inheriting AbstractBaseUser increase efficiency and productivity, if any?**

I guess `set_password()` function may relieve the burden of manually encrypting input password with bcrypt; however, additional work is needed to create a UserManager class, refer to my custom User model with `auth.get_user_model()` function (django documentation says this way is recommended to return the currently active user model) instead of simply referring to it as 'User', and etc.
Your help will be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: you could refer to this doc to create a custom user model https://kite.com/blog/python/custom-django-user-model/

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the documentation of [User model in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/auth/#user-model), the advantages of using AbstractUser to create your own user model are:

1. It comes with the integration with Group and Permission models which would help you build your [authentication system](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model) and authorisation system in your apps.
2. The UserManager is quite powerful as it also provide util functions such as "set_password", "has_perm" and "is_authenticated" etc.

Based on the above, you can just [inherit the AbstractUser](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#using-a-custom-user-model-when-starting-a-project) to build your own User model, so you don't need to **reinventing the wheel**. It provides both flexibilities and functionalities. You could also customise lots of things in your own User model by overriding its own methods.

In your case, you could just use the following code and specify your [AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.User'](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model) in your settings:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser


class User(AbstractUser):
    realname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    birthday = models.DateField()
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
```

Comment: Thank you! Can I use UserManager's "has_perm" method to check the user's status (membership status, for instance) and allow access to certain pages or information in my website, not an admin page? Or should I just use a token and @evaluate_status decorator to give different access to users with varying status?

Comment: Membership is a new concept thus you would need additional methods to check user's membership rather than permission. And you could also use Group to act as kinda membership to check whether a user is in a Group or not.
If you don't want a user to access your ADMIN page, you could simply set is_staff status to False for a user instance. 
Depending on your implementation of authentication, your token can generally be mapping to your user objects in your views. And you would also need to implement your own authorisation system to check a user's permission and return appropriate pages.